# postgres index performance unclear

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I recently encountered and solved a Problem - but I do not get why there even was a Problem to begin with.

simplified said, i have 3 tables in a postgres 10.5 database:

```
entities (id, name)
entities_to_stuff(
    id, 
    entities_id -> fk entities.id, 
    stuff_id -> fk stuff.id, 
    unique constraint (entity_id, stuff_id)
)
stuff(id, name)
```

after inserting about 200k records, selects on the query:

```
select * from entities_to_stuff where entities_id = 1;
```

started to take 100 - 400 ms.

As is understood, creating a unique constraint, creates an index on the unique fields. so i have an index on `(entities_id, stuff_id)`, `entities_id` being the "leftmost" column.

according to the docs, queries including the leftmost column are the most efficient ( [postgres docs on this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html) ) - so i assumed this index would do for me.

So i checked the execution plan - it wasn't using the index.
So, just to be sure i did:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

and re ran the query - still took well over 100 ms most of the time.

I then got annoyed and created this index

```
create index "idx_entities_id" on "entities_to_stuff" ("entities_id");
```

and suddenly it takes 0.2 ms or even less to run and the execution plan also uses it when sequential scans are enabled.

How is this index orders of magnitudes faster than the one already existing?

Edit:

execution plan after generating the additional index:

```
Index Scan using idx_entities_id on entities_to_stuff (cost=0.00..12.04 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.049..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (entities_id = 199283)
Planning time: 0.378 ms
Execution time: 0.073 ms
```

plan with just the unique constraint, seq_scan=on

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..38679.87 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=344.321..1740.861 rows=1 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 0
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on entities_to_stuff  (cost=0.00..37679.67 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=344.088..1739.684 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (entities_id = 199283)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2907419
Planning time: 0.241 ms
Execution time: 740.888 ms
```

plan with constraint, seq-scan = off

```
Index Scan using uq_entities_to_stuff on entities_to_stuff  (cost=0.43..66636.34 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.385..553.066 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (entities_id = 199283)
Planning time: 0.082 ms
Execution time: 553.103 ms
```

Comment: Is `entities_id` the same column as `entity_id`? Did you run `analyze entities_to_stuff` to update the statistics on the table?

Comment: yes, i just cleared all names to make sure i do not accidentally disclose something

Comment: @billdoor: a_horse had *2* requests, you missed the 2nd. And please disclose the actual table definition of `entities_to_stuff` (`CREATE TABLE` statement). Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info. Do you still see the big difference after `REINDEX INDEX  uq_entities_to_stuff` and `ANALYZE entities_to_stuff`?

Comment: i figured out the problem, at its root it seems to stem from the fact that the one implementing the code, always deletes all entries from entities_to_stuff and inserts the new values, when a notification is sent to "update" these assignments. this lead to permanent delete + insert of the same values over and over, which broke the indexes after some time and made postgres conclude that scanning was indeed better.